# AKS user node pools are recreating for every terraform run

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks

AKS user node pools are recreating for every terraform run, but system node pool is not recreating.
Below is the code for system node pool

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
#count = var.create_aks_cluster ? 1 : 0
name = var.aks_cluster_name
location = var.location
resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
dns_prefix = var.dns_prefix
kubernetes_version = var.kubernetes_version
private_cluster_enabled = false
sku_tier = var.sku_tier
lifecycle {
ignore_changes = [
default_node_pool[0].node_count
]
}
```

below is the code for user node pool

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aks_cluster_user_pool" {

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      node_count
    ]
  }

  for_each = var.additional_node_pools

  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.id
  name                  = each.value.node_os == "Linux" ? substr(each.key, 0, 6) : substr(each.key, 0, 12)
  orchestrator_version  = var.kubernetes_version
  mode                  = "User"
  node_count            = each.value.node_count
  vm_size               = each.value.vm_size
  availability_zones    = each.value.zones
  enable_auto_scaling   = each.value.cluster_auto_scaling

  os_type   = each.value.node_os
  min_count = each.value.cluster_auto_scaling_min_count
  max_count = each.value.cluster_auto_scaling_max_count
  max_pods  = var.max_pods_per_node

  node_taints = each.value.taints
  #vnet_subnet_id        =var.subnet_aks_id
}
```

How to avoid recreating of user node pools? we are running terraform using azure pipeline

Comment: What does Terraform tell you is changed about the user pools when you run `terraform plan`?

Answer (score 1):

Because You have set `mode = "User"` in user_node_pool.

I think You have to create other node_pull with `mode = "System"`.

Answer (score 0):

below is the terraform plan log:

```
  # module.aks_cluster.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool.aks_cluster_user_pool["pool1"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aks_cluster_user_pool" {
      - enable_host_encryption = false -> null
      - enable_node_public_ip  = false -> null
      ~ id                     = "agentPools/pool1" -> (known after apply)
        name                   = "pool1"
      - node_labels            = {} -> null
      ~ node_taints            = [ # forces replacement
          + "CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoSchedule",
        ]
      ~ os_disk_size_gb        = 128 -> (known after apply)
      - tags                   = {} -> null
      - vnet_subnet_id         = "ventsubnet-id" -> null # forces replacement
        # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

   # module.aks_cluster.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool.aks_cluster_user_pool["pool2"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aks_cluster_user_pool" {
      - enable_host_encryption = false -> null
      - enable_node_public_ip  = false -> null
      ~ id                     = "agentPools/pool2" -> (known after apply)
      - max_count              = 0 -> null
      - min_count              = 0 -> null
        name                   = "pool2"
      - node_labels            = {} -> null
      ~ node_taints            = [ # forces replacement
          + "CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoSchedule",
        ]
      ~ os_disk_size_gb        = 128 -> (known after apply)
      - tags                   = {} -> null
      - vnet_subnet_id         = "ventsubnet" -> null # forces replacement
        # (12 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```